# Pass-by-value (StringBuilder vs String)

Tags: java, string, parameter-passing, stringbuilder, pass-by-value

I do not understand why *System.out.println(name)* outputs *Sam* without being affected by the method's concat function, while *System.out.println(names)* outputs *Sam4* as a result of the method's append method. Why is StringBuilder affected and not String? Normally, calling methods on a reference to an object affects the caller, so I do not understand why the String result remains unchanged. Thanks in advance

```
public static String speak(String name) {
    name = name.concat("4");
    return name;
}

public static StringBuilder test(StringBuilder names) {
    names = names.append("4");
    return names; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "Sam";
    speak(name);
    System.out.println(name); //Sam
    StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder("Sam");
    test(names);
    System.out.println(names); //Sam4
}
```

Comment: A lot of answers here, basically all saying the same thing. Hard to choose one to upvote :)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Luckily you don't need to choose just one ;)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle as Mark Rotteveel said, Helenesh is the one who has to make that tough choice ;)

Comment: name and names are local references, in semantic similair to pointers being assigned, only StringBuilder.append works on the referenced object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because when you call `speak(name);`, inside speak when you do

```
name = name.concat("4");
```

it creates a new object because `String`s are immutable. When you change the original string it creates a new object,I agree that you are returning it but you are not catching it.

So essentially what you are doing is :

```
name(new) = name(original) + '4'; // but you should notice that both the names are different objects.
```

try

```
String name = "Sam";
name = speak(name);
```

Of course now I think there is no need to explain why it's working with `StringBuilder` unless if you don't know that `StringBuilder` is mutable.

Comment: "it creates a new object because Strings are immutable." There is no concept of "mutability" in the language. It returns a new object because that's what the method is documented to do. It doesn't modify the object it's called on, again, because that's what the method is documented to do.

Comment: @newacct Sorry sir, I am sure I don't know as much as you do but I thought OP would not be happy if I say "It returns a new object because it's method is documented to do so". So that's why I wanted to give some reasoning behind that.

Comment: But we only say the class is "immutable" only because all of its methods are documented to not modify it. So it would be circular reasoning to say that the methods don't modify it because it is immutable.

Comment: @newacct may be it's like "Chicken or the egg" :P

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the [Javadoc for `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html), one will read that

> [...] String objects are **immutable** [...].

This means [`concat(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) does not change the `String` itself, but constructs a new `String`.

[`StringBuilder`s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), on the other hand, are mutable. By calling [`append(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)), the object itself is mutated.

Comment: Immutable by design, reflection certainly can change the String content; and this is what you do, when working with sensitive String-s like passwords.

Answer (score 4):

Because `String` is immutable and hence `String#concat` does not modify the original String instance, it only returns a new `String` while the original is left unmodified, while `StringBuilder` is mutable and the change is reflected in the `StringBuilder` instance passed as parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, what is `speak` method doing?

First of all,

```
name.concat("4");
```

creates new object, which is equal to `name`, concatenated with `"4"`.

So, the line

```
name = name.concat(4);
```

redefines **local** (for `speak` method) variable `name`.

Then you return the reference to this new value with

```
return name;
```

So, the original variable, passed within method is not modified, but the method returns modified value.

In the `test` method you actually modify variable without modifying the reference (the `StringBuilder` class is mutable, so variable if this type can be modified).

Then we can see another question arising: why `StringBuilder.append` returns value, where it can seem redundant. The answer to this question lies in the description of "builder" pattern, for which it is the usual way of implementing modification methods. See [wikipedia on Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Answer (score 3):

When you invoke `speak(name)` it computes the new value, but discards it.

If you replace it with

```
name = speak(name);
```

the result will be the one you expect.

With the `StringBuilder`, the object you pass is mutable: so

```
names.append(names);
```

changes the state of the current object (it also returns a reference to the same object, which is just a convenience to allow you to write code like `names.append(...).append(...)` etc.). So in the case of the `StringBuilder`, the object you are referencing when you call the method has actually changed, hence you see the changes.

Comment: You didn't answer the question: why it works with StringBuilder?

Answer (score 3):

`String` is immutable in java. As soon as you invoke `concat` method on name. A new string is created and while you are playing with the old reference in `System.out.println(name)`.If you want to use the modified string you should explicitly return the reference.
While `StringBuilder` is mutable and it returns the same reference always.

Answer (score 3):

In your method `speak`, the [`concat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat-java.lang.String-) method returns a **new String**, the original object it was called on is unchanged (strings are immutable). As documented:

> If the length of the argument string is `0`, then this `String` object is returned. Otherwise, a `String` object is returned that represents a character sequence that is the concatenation of the character sequence represented by this `String` object and the character sequence represented by the argument string.

Calling `name.concat("4")` is the equivalent of `name + "4"`.

In your `test` method the [`append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.String-) method **modifies the content** of the `StringBuilder`. As documented:

> The principal operations on a `StringBuilder` are the `append` and `insert` methods, which are overloaded so as to accept data of any type. Each effectively converts a given datum to a string and then appends or inserts the characters of that string to the string builder. The `append` method always adds these characters at the end of the builder; the `insert` method adds the characters at a specified point.

In your main method both `name` and `names` are still **the same** object as before the method call, but the content of `name` is unchanged as strings are immutable, while the content of `names` has been changed.

If instead you had used the return values of both methods, then you would have the result you were expecting.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `String` is an **immutable class** in Java. An **immutable class** is simply a class whose instances cannot be modified. All information in an instance is initialized when the instance is created and the information can not be modified.

Second, in java parameters are sent by values and not by reference.

In your method 'test' you don't need `names = names.append("4")`, instead `names.append("4")` will be enough .

If you check java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for String object, you will see that most of the methods there, including **concat**, will generate a new String.

So to have on output *Sam4* also for the String, you will need in main method to have this `name = speak(name)`.

Answer (score 0):

**String**

> String is immutable  ( once created can not be changed )object  . The
>   object created as a String is stored in the  Constant String Pool  . 
>   Every immutable object in Java is thread safe ,that implies String is
>   also thread safe . String can not be used by two threads
>   simultaneously. String  once assigned can not be changed.
>
> String  demo = " hello " ; // The above object is stored in constant
>   string pool and its value can not be modified.
>
> demo="Bye" ;     //new "Bye" string is created in constant pool and
>   referenced by the demo variable              // "hello" string still
>   exists in string constant pool and its value is not overrided but we
>   lost reference to the  "hello"string

**StringBuilder**

> StringBuilder  is same as the StringBuffer , that is it stores the
>   object in heap and it can also be modified . The main difference
>   between the StringBuffer and StringBuilder is that StringBuilder is
>   also not thread safe.  StringBuilder is fast as it is not thread safe
>   .

For more details check [this](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/06/difference-between-string-stringbuilder.html)

***Conclusion:*** 
You don't need to re-assign the value again to `StringBuilder` as it is already a reference
test method should be

```
public static void test(StringBuilder names) {
    names.append("4");
   }
```

but speak should be

```
 String name = "Sam";
   name =  speak(name);
```

Comment: That's not what it is being asked.